# Can we get bounce effect onmouseover without applying jquery function?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I am designing a menu, though if I want a bounce effect on mouse over to current element, but I don't want to use jquery function for it. 
Can we write code in css3?
I am trying with the code-

```
tab-switch li a.current {

background-image://any transition??//

     -webkit-transition:easeoutbounce 1s linear;
     -moz-transition: easeoutbounce 1s linear;
     -o-transition: easeoutbounce 1s linear;
     -ms-transition: easeoutbounce 1s linear;
     transition: easeoutbounce 1s linear;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url('images/bgs/selectedmenu.png');}
```

Comment: what's with the `background-image://any transition??//` in your code?

Comment: can i have any transition with background-image?

Comment: IMO you get the transition on the full HTML element. If the element has a BG image, you should have that too [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp).

Comment: [Such a classic question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+menu).  Personally my 2008 opinion is I think you should stop that and just totally use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can have bouncing transitions by using a custom [**timing function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/timing-function) for your transition.

See [**a few examples of bouncing transitions on hover for background images**](http://dabblet.com/gist/4474482) (created using gradients) that I did. Basically, the idea is that you use a cubic bezier timing function (**`cubic-bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2)`** - **`x1`** and **`x2`** must be in the closed interval **`[0, 1]`** ), where the second value (**`y1`**) is > 1 and/ or the fourth value (**`y2`**) is < 0 (which means that your function is increasing then decreasing, then increasing again between 0% and 100%, and not strictly increasing as it would be if you did not have a bounce - you can visualize the function by hovering over the cubic-bezier code in the Dabblet CSS panel).

The cubic-bezier functions I've used in my examples were `cubic-bezier(0, 3.5, 1, -2.5)`, `cubic-bezier(0, 3.25, 1, -2.25)` and `cubic-bezier(0, 3, 1, -2)`, but you can use any values you would like. In general, the higher the second value is and the lower (or higher in absolute value) the fourth value is, then the more pronounced the bounce becomes.

**CSS** code for the last example (bouncing gradient angle):

```
.p4 {
    background: linear-gradient(left top, orangered 49%, lemonchiffon 51%)
            50% 50%;
    background-size: 100% 130%;
    transition: 2.75s cubic-bezier(0, 3.25, 1, -2.25);
}
.p4:hover {
    background-size: 100% 280%;
}
```

If you need more than this, then you'll have to use [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes) - see this [**quick example**](http://dabblet.com/gist/4474556) I just did.

**CSS**:

```
.p0 {
    background-image:
    url(http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2012-49-a-small_web.jpg), 
    url(http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2002-24-a-small_web.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.p0:hover {
    animation: ani0 4s forwards;
}
@keyframes ani0 {
    10% { background-size: 50% 75%, 100% 100%; }
    20% { background-size: 50% 50%, 100% 100%; }
    30% { background-position: 50% 50%; background-size: 50% 25%, 100% 100%; }
    30% { background-position: 25% 50%, 50% 50%;
        background-size: 25% 25%, 100% 100%; }
    40% { background-position: 25% 0, 50% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 50% 0, 50% 50%; }
    60% { background-position: 100% 25%, 50% 50%; }
    70% { background-position: 75% 50%, 50% 50%;
        background-size: 25% 25%, 100% 100%; }
    80% { background-position: 50% 100%, 50% 50%; }
    90% { background-position: 0 50%, 50% 50%; }
    100% { background-size: 0 0, 100% 100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like asad said, you can use [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/). but to answer your question, use 100% css.

Here's a demo using pure css (hover to bounce): http://jsfiddle.net/yXJ3G/

The key is to add a hover class to the bounce effect. that way there's no need for the JS/jQuery.

```
.bounce:hover {
-webkit-animation-name: bounce;
-moz-animation-name: bounce;
-o-animation-name: bounce;
animation-name: bounce;
}
```